# Android CardView Elevation not working anymore

Tags: android, cardview, elevation

I am facing a strange problem that android `CardView` `cardElevation` is not working anymore at any API level, even my old projects are not showing `cardElevation` which were functional in past, even I tried completely empty project but got the same issue.

There are lot of issues have already been discussed related to this, I have tried every possible solution on the internet and on this site but I couldn't solve the issue. I am using the latest version `3.3` of Android Studio, Is there any bug in Android Studio or am I missing anything?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardMaxElevation="6dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try giving it a margin of 2 dp

Comment: I have already tried this to

Comment: Can you show me your mobile previews and build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line from your manifest file `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`
 then build the project again and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For me using

```
android:outlineProvider="background"
```

on material card view solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Use this dependencies you can achieve the elevation from Post API 21

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Ok I'll try it and let you know, but would like to explain why prior is not working as it was working before..